# Struggling to understand when query data from NodeJs/Express to Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, mysql-workbench

i am confused when reading the data that is returned when i do the below query from my NodeJS.

```
 connection.query("SELECT * FROM  users WHERE email=?;", [x1.Email], function (
    err,
    results
  ) {
// before i can just do console.log("email is", results[0].email); and it worked fine

    console.log("email is", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))[0].email); 
}
```

**Scenario 1:**

when i created a simple table in the MySQL and query data and can extract email from it easily as

```
results[0].email
```

**Scenario 2:**
when i created the same table again using my SQL workbench and query data to extract email from it then the results[0].email doesnt work and i can see the data is returned as RowDataPacket{} and forced to use,

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))[0].email
```

**It does work now but struggle to understand why** *RowDataPacket* **appears the second time and not before and how come the JSON technique works here.**

Below is the users table when it is craeted using Mysql workbench.

```
mysql> show create table users;
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table




                                           |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `create_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,       
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `userlogin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

.
really appreciate for the help.

Comment: Don't confuse with rawpacket it only indicates that result is a arrar of rawpacket.
You can still use console.log(results[0].email) it will display email only

Comment: @RahulKumar its quite strange but now after some time i tried again as  results[0].email and it did work fine as well.